# SQL runs in Access but not in ASP.NET webform

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, ms-access

I'm running the following statement:

```
SELECT product_naam, omschrijving 
FROM product 
WHERE (product_naam LIKE '*' + ? + '*') OR (omschrijving LIKE '*' + ? + '*')
```

It runs fine in Microsoft Access, but when I run it in ASP.NET with a grid view output, it does not give me any output.

Comment: What values do you put after LIKE statements? Are you quering MSAccess or MSSQL DB?

Comment: Are you using OLEDB with ASP.NET?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing the wild cards from * to %

```
SELECT product_naam, omschrijving 
FROM product 
WHERE (product_naam LIKE '%' + ? + '%') OR (omschrijving LIKE '%' + ? + '%')
```

Answer (score 1):

In ADO.NET `%` is a wildcard corresponding to `*` in MSAccess. Change your query like below and it should work:

```
SELECT product_naam, omschrijving 
FROM product 
WHERE (product_naam LIKE '%' + ? + '%') OR (omschrijving LIKE '%' + ? + '%')
```

More details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa140104%28v=office.10%29.aspx)